# how to prove sphere tangent plane in parametric form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vectors, parametric, cross-product, spheres

We can express sphere using parametric form.
For example when sphere's radius is 1.

x = x($\phi, $$\theta$) = cos($\phi$)sin($\theta$)

y = y($\phi, $$\theta$) = cos($\phi$)cos($\theta$)

z = z($\phi, $$\theta$) = sin($\phi$)

In my book, the tangent plane's normal vector is **n** = $\frac {\partial p}{\partial \theta}$ × $\frac {\partial p}{\partial \phi}$
(p is any point on the sphere)

I could not prove this. How to prove it?

Why there is cross operation?

Comment: The cross product gives as output a vector perpendicular to the terms involved.

Comment: I knew the fact but instead, I wonder why it used partial differentials

Comment: A partial differential is a derivative along a direction. You are cross-multiplying two vectors tangential to the surface.